# suggestion needed for storage system for an crawler

Tags: c++, mongodb, hbase, hypertable

I am planning to write a web crawler in c++ which crawls N number of pages daily. The main problem is that I am getting confusing with storage system . So I need a distributed db which efficient to store my crawled datas. Can anyone suggest me db which fulfill conditions?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB is likely a good fit since it supports almost all requirements in a straight forward and high-efficient way (including a nice query API). Distribution is accomplished through "Sharding".

Do not ask for a comparision of the databases (often discussed including stackoverflow ).

Answer (score -1):

unless N is very large, or you plan on storing a lot of versions, you probably don't need a distributed DB.  Try starting with MySQL